# How can I send Subtitle Text to Python with Php Laravel?

Tags: python, php, laravel, moviepy

I would like to send subtitle text from php controller to python program that create video with subtitles using movipy library. I managed to send subtitle text but subtitles only appear started of video. And the time & text informations didn't seperated properly with srt.parse function. I managed the created video from srt file but I would like to use text instead of file. Python program interpret whole posted text as a sentence like below. Can you give me an idea please for solving the problem?

```
[Subtitle(content=u'', index=None, proprietary='\\r\\n As someone with an AI background, \\r\\n\\r\\n 00:00:01,879 --> 00:00:04,277 \\r\\n I think you can probably explain to us', end=datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 879000), start=datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 319000))]
```

My php controller is below.

```
public function store()
{
    $str = <<<TEXT
                00:00:00,319 --> 00:00:01,879 As someone with an AI background, 00:00:01,879 --> 00:00:04,277 I think you can probably explain to us, 00:00:04,277 --> 00:00:06,916 you know, this whole hype of generative AI, right?   
            TEXT;
    $py_output = exec('python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xampp...\\main.py ' . json_encode($str) . '');
    var_dump($py_output);
    return view('videotest.store');
}
```

My main.py is below

```
import sys
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip

textList = sys.argv[1]
subtitle_generator = srt.parse(textList)
subtitles = list(subtitle_generator)
mp4filename = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xampp..\\myvideo.mp4"

def create_subtitle_clips(subtitles, videosize,fontsize=24, font='Arial', color='yellow', debug = False):
    subtitle_clips = []
    i = 0
    while subtitles[i:]:
        start_time = subtitles[i].start.seconds
        end_time = subtitles[i].end.seconds
        duration = end_time - start_time
        video_width, video_height = videosize
        text_clip = TextClip(subtitles[i].proprietary, fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color=color, bg_color = 'black',size=(video_width*3/4, None), method='caption').set_start(start_time).set_duration(duration)
        subtitle_x_position = 'center'
        subtitle_y_position = video_height* 4 / 5 
        text_position = (subtitle_x_position, subtitle_y_position)             
        subtitle_clips.append(text_clip.set_position(text_position))
        i = i + 1

    return subtitle_clips

video = VideoFileClip(mp4filename)

begin,end= mp4filename.split(".mp4")
output_video_file = begin+'_subtitled5'+".mp4"
subtitle_clips = create_subtitle_clips(subtitles,video.size)
final_video = CompositeVideoClip([video] + subtitle_clips)
final_video.write_videofile(output_video_file)
```

Comment: There seems to be some ambiguity about newline characters in your sample input.

Comment: @mickmackusa I added newline charcter to text like below..

Comment: Adding an answer does not clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the subtitle text is correctly formatted and parsed into separate subtitles with their respective timings.

`Ensure your subtitle text is in a proper SRT format`

```
1
00:00:00,500 --> 00:00:02,000
Subtitle 1 text here.

2
00:00:02,500 --> 00:00:04,000
Subtitle 2 text here.
```

In Laravel properly escape and pass the subtitle text. You can use base64 encoding to ensure that newlines and other special characters are preserved when passing the string to Python.

```
public function store()
{
    $str = <<<TEXT
1
00:00:00,319 --> 00:00:01,879 As someone with an AI background,
2
00:00:01,879 --> 00:00:04,277 I think you can probably explain to us,
3
00:00:04,277 --> 00:00:06,916 you know, this whole hype of generative AI, right?
TEXT;
    $encodedStr = base64_encode($str); // Encode the string
    $py_output = exec('python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xampp...\\main.py ' . escapeshellarg($encodedStr));
    var_dump($py_output);
    return view('videotest.store');
}
```

In your Python script, decode the input string before parsing it with `srt.parse`.

```
import sys
import base64
import srt

# Decode the input string
encoded_text = sys.argv[1]
decoded_text = base64.b64decode(encoded_text).decode('utf-8')

subtitle_generator = srt.parse(decoded_text)
subtitles = list(subtitle_generator)

# your other code....
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my controller like below and it can use as srt format.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
        $all = json_decode($request->items, true);
        $result = '';
        foreach($all as $key=>$item){
            $result .= "\n" . $all[$key]['start'] . '-->' . $all[$key]['end'] . ' ' . $all[$key]['subtitle'] . "\n\n";
        }

        $str = <<<TEXT
        $result
        TEXT;

        $encodedStr = base64_encode($str); 
        $file_path = app_path('Http/Controllers/Api/myvideo.mp4');
        $py_output = exec('python ' . app_path('Http/Controllers/Api/main.py') . ' ' . escapeshellarg($encodedStr) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($file_path));
        var_dump($py_output);
 }
```